# How Kotlin coroutines are better than RxKotlin?

Tags: kotlin, rx-kotlin

Why would I want to use Kotlin's coroutines?

It seems that the RxKotlin library is much more versatile.
Kotlin's coroutines look significantly less powerful and more cumbersome to use in comparison.

I base my opinion on coroutines on [this design talk by Andrey Breslav (JetBrains)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4W3ruTWUhpw)

Slideshow from the talk is [accessible here.](https://www.slideshare.net/abreslav/jvmls-2016-coroutines-in-kotlin)

---

EDIT (thanks to @hotkey):

Better source on the current state of coroutines [here.](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Parts of this answer are irrelevant since Coroutines now have the flow API, very similar to Rx one. If you want an up-to-date answer, jump to the last edit.

There is two parts in Rx; the Observable pattern, and a solid set of operators to manipulate, transform and combine them. The Observable pattern, by itself, doesn't do a lot. Same with Coroutines; it's just another paradigm to deal with asynchronism. You can compare the pro/cons of callbacks, Observable and coroutines to solve a given problem, but you can't compare a paradigm with a fully featured library. It's like comparing a language with a framework.

How Kotlin coroutines are better than RxKotlin ? Didn't used coroutines yet, but it's look similar to async/wait in C#. You just write sequential code, everything is as easy as writing synchronous code ... except it execute asynchronously. It's easier to grasp.

Why would I want to use kotlin coroutines ? I will answer for myself. Most of the time I will stick to Rx, because I favor event-driven architecture. But should arise the situation where I am writing sequential code, and I need to call an asynchronous method in the middle, I will happily leverage coroutines to keep it that way and avoiding wrapping everything in Observable.

**Edit**: Now that I am using coroutines it's time for an update.

RxKotlin is just syntactic sugar to use RxJava in Kotlin, so I will speak about RxJava and not RxKotlin in the following. Coroutines are a lower lever and more general concept than RxJava, they serve others use-cases. That said, there is one use-case where you could compare RxJava and coroutines (`channel`), it's passing around data asynchronously. Coroutines have a clear advantage over RxJava here:

### Coroutines are better to deal with resources

- In RxJava you can assign computations to schedulers but `subscribeOn()` and `ObserveOn()`are confusing. Every coroutine is given a thread context and return to parent context. For a channel, both side (producer, consumer) execute on his own context. Coroutines are more intuitive on thread or thread pool affectation.
- Coroutines give more control on when those computation occur. You can for example pass hand (`yield`), prioritize (`select`), parallelize (multiple `producer`/`actor` on `channel`) or lock resource (`Mutex`) for a given computation. It may not matter on server (where RxJava came first) but on resources limited environment this level of control may be required.
- Due to it's reactive nature, backpressure doesn't fit well in RxJava. In the other end `send()` to channel is a suspensive function that suspend when channel capacity is reached. It's out-of-the-box backpressure given by nature. You could also `offer()` to channel, in which case the call never suspend but return `false` in case the channel is full, effectively reproducing `onBackpressureDrop()` from RxJava. Or you could just write your own custom backpressure logic, which won't be difficult with coroutines, especially compared to do the same with RxJava.

There is another use-case, where coroutines shine and this will answer your second question "Why would I want to use Kotlin coroutines?". Coroutines are the perfect replacement for background threads or `AsyncTask` (Android). It's as easy as `launch { someBlockingFunction() }`. Of course you could achieve this with RxJava too, using `Schedulers` and `Completable` perhaps. You won't (or little) use the Observer pattern and the operators which are the signature of RxJava, a hint that this work is out of scope for RxJava. RxJava complexity (a useless tax here) will make your code more verbose and less clean than Coroutine's version.

Readability matters. On this regard, RxJava and coroutines approach differ a lot. Coroutines are simpler than RxJava. If you are not at ease with `map()`, `flatmap()` and functional reactive programming in general, coroutines manipulations are easier, involving basics instructions: `for`, `if`, `try/catch` ... But I personally find coroutine's code harder to understand for non-trivial tasks. Especially it involves more nesting and indentation whereas operator chaining in RxJava keep everything in line. Functional-style programming make processing more explicit. On top of that RxJava can solve complex transformations with a few standard operators from their rich (OK, way too rich) operator set. RxJava shine when you have complex data flows requiring a lot of combinations and transformations.

I hope those considerations will help you choose the right tool given your needs.

**Edit:** Coroutine now have flow, an API very, very similar to Rx. One could compare pro/cons of each, but the truth is the differences are minor.

Coroutines as it's core is a concurrency design pattern, with add-on libraries, one of those being a stream API similar to Rx. Obviously, Coroutines having a far broader scope than Rx, there is a lot of things that Coroutines can that Rx can't, and I can't list them all. But usually if I use Coroutines in one of my project it boil down to one reason:

### Coroutines are better at removing callback from your code

I avoid using callback wich harm readability too much. Coroutines make asynchronous code simple and easy to write. By leveraging the suspend keyword, your code look like synchronous one.

I have seen Rx used in project mostly for the same purpose of replacing callback, but if you don't plan to modify your architecture to commit to the reactive pattern, Rx will be a burden. Consider this interface:

```
interface Foo {
   fun bar(callback: Callback)
}
```

The Coroutine equivalent is more explicit, with a return type and the keyword suspend indicating it's an asynchronous operation.

```
interface Foo {
   suspend fun bar: Result
}
```

But there is a problem with the Rx equivalent:

```
interface Foo {
   fun bar: Single<Result>
}
```

When you call bar() in the callback or Coroutine version, you trigger the computation; with the Rx version, you get a representation of a computation that you can trigger at will. You need to call bar() then subscribing to the Single. Usually not a big deal, but it's a little confusing for beginner and can lead to subtle problem.

One exemple of such problems, suppose the callback bar function is implemented as such:

```
fun bar(callback: Callback) {
   setCallback(callback)
   refreshData()
}
```

If you don't port it properly, you will end with a Single that can be triggered only once because refreshData() is called in bar() function and not at subscription time. A beginner mistake, granted, but the thing is Rx is way more than a callback replacement and a lot of developers struggle to grasp Rx.

If your objective is to transform an asynchronous task from callback to a nicer paradigm, Coroutines are a perfect fit whereas Rx add some complexity.

Comment: So instead of wrapping everything in an Observable, you will wrap everything in an Future.

Comment: Fortunately, Kotlin coroutines are quite unlike C# and JS and don't require wrapping your code in a Future. You _can_ use futures with Kotlin coroutines, but _idiomatic_ code that is based on Kotlin coroutines uses almost no futures at all.

Comment: One can do event driven architecture using channels fairly easily.

Comment: do you think i can use both in some situations?

Comment: Personally I would avoid mixing Coroutines and RxJava, for consistency and complexity reasons. Depending your use-case, you may consider Coroutines with LiveData or the newly introduced type Flow: [Roman Elizarov: Cold flows, hot channels](https://medium.com/@elizarov/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9)

Comment: In addition, ‘’’map()’’’ or ‘’’flatMap()’’’ is available in Coroutin too. The role of ‘’’flow’’’ of Coroutine is similiar with Observable in Rx and you can also use so many operator for this. Plus, Coroutine is significantly faster than Rx and use less resources than Rx. Let me show this article. https://link.medium.com/o1QNGL2bvZ

Comment: I'm not sure how an answer gets by without mentioning `Flow` type.  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html .  That is the most comparable part of coroutines to RxJava

Comment: That's right, but `Flow` wasn't available when the question and the answers were written.

Answer (score 125):

I know RxJava very well and I've recently switched to Kotlin Coroutines and Flow.

RxKotlin is basically the same as RxJava, it just adds some syntactic sugar to make it more comfortable / idiomatic writing RxJava code in Kotlin.

A "fair" comparison between RxJava and Kotlin Coroutines should include Flow in the mix and I'm gonna try to explain why here. This is gonna be a bit long but I'll try to keep it as simple as I can with examples.

With RxJava you have different objects (since version 2):

```kotlin
// 0-n events without backpressure management
fun observeEventsA(): Observable<String>

// 0-n events with explicit backpressure management
fun observeEventsB(): Flowable<String>

// exactly 1 event
fun encrypt(original: String): Single<String>

// 0-1 events
fun cached(key: String): Maybe<MyData>

// just completes with no specific results
fun syncPending(): Completable
```

In Kotlin coroutines + flow you do not need many entities cause if you do not have a stream of events you can just use simple coroutines (suspending functions):

```kotlin
// 0-n events, the backpressure is automatically taken care off
fun observeEvents(): Flow<String>

// exactly 1 event
suspend fun encrypt(original: String): String

// 0-1 events
suspend fun cached(key: String): MyData?

// just completes with no specific results
suspend fun syncPending()
```

Bonus: Kotlin Flow / Coroutines support `null` values (support removed with RxJava 2)

**Suspending functions** are what the name hints: they are functions that can pause the execution of the code and resume it later when the function is completed; this allows you to write code that feels more natural.

### What about the operators?

With RxJava you have so many operators (`map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, `switchMap`, ...), and for most of them there's a version for each entity type (`Single.map()`, `Observable.map()`, ...).

Kotlin Coroutines + Flow **do not need that many operators**, let's see why with some examples of the most common operators:

**map()**

RxJava:

```kotlin
fun getPerson(id: String): Single<Person>
fun observePersons(): Observable<Person>

fun getPersonName(id: String): Single<String> {
  return getPerson(id)
     .map { it.firstName }
}

fun observePersonsNames(): Observable<String> {
  return observePersons()
     .map { it.firstName }
}
```

Kotlin coroutines + Flow

```kotlin
suspend fun getPerson(id: String): Person
fun observePersons(): Flow<Person>

suspend fun getPersonName(id: String): String? {
  return getPerson(id).firstName
}

fun observePersonsNames(): Flow<String> {
  return observePersons()
     .map { it.firstName }
}
```

You do not need an operator for the "single" case and it is fairly similar for the `Flow` case.

**flatMap()**

The `flatMap` operator and his siblings `switchMap`, `contactMap` exist to allow you to combine different RxJava objects and thus execute potentially asynchronous code while mapping your events.

Say you need, for each person, to grab from a database (or remote service) it's insurance

RxJava

```kotlin
fun fetchInsurance(insuranceId: String): Single<Insurance>

fun getPersonInsurance(id: String): Single<Insurance> {
  return getPerson(id)
    .flatMap { person ->
      fetchInsurance(person.insuranceId)
    }
}

fun observePersonsInsurances(): Observable<Insurance> {
  return observePersons()
    .flatMap { person ->
      fetchInsurance(person.insuranceId) // this is a Single
          .toObservable() // flatMap expect an Observable
    }
}
```

Let's see with Kotlin Coroutines + Flow

```kotlin
suspend fun fetchInsurance(insuranceId: String): Insurance

suspend fun getPersonInsurance(id: String): Insurance {
  val person = getPerson(id)
  return fetchInsurance(person.insuranceId)
}

fun observePersonsInsurances(): Flow<Insurance> {
  return observePersons()
    .map { person ->
      fetchInsurance(person.insuranceId)
    }
}
```

Like before, with the simple coroutine case we do not need operators, we just write the code like we would if it wasn't async, just using suspending functions.

And with `Flow` that is NOT a typo, there's no need for a `flatMap` operator, we can just use `map`. And the reason is that map lambda is a suspending function! We can execute suspending code in it!!!

We don't need another operator just for that.

> **I cheated a bit here**
>
> Rx `flatMap`, `switchMap` and `concatMap` behave slightly differently.
> Rx `flatMap` generates a new stream for each event and then merges them all together: the order of the new stream's events you receive in the output is undetermined, it might not match the order or the events in input
>
> Rx `concatMap` "fixes" that and guarantees you will get each new stream in the same order as your input events
>
> Rx `switchMap` will instead dispose of any previously running stream when it gets a new event, only the last input received matters with this operator
>
> So you see, it isn't true that `Flow.map` is the same, it is actually more similar to Rx `concatMap`, which is the more natural behavior you expect from a map operator.
>
> But it is true you need fewer operators, inside map you can do any async operation you want and reproduce the behavior of `flatMap` because it is a suspendable function. The actual equivalent operator to RxJava `flatMap` is `Flow.flatMapMerge` operator.
>
> The equivalent of the RxJava `switchMap` can be achieved in Flow by using the `conflate()` operator before the `map` operator.

For more complex stuff you can use the Flow `transform()` operator which for every event emits a Flow of your choice.

**Every Flow operator accepts a suspending function!**

In the previous paragraph I told you *I cheated*. But the key getaway of what I meant by *Flow do not need as many operators* is that most operator's callbacks are suspending function.

So say you need to `filter()` but your filter needs to perform a network call to know if you should keep the value or not, with RxJava you need to combine multiple operators with unreadable code, with Flow you can just use `filter()`!

```kotlin
fun observePersonsWithValidInsurance(): Flow<Person> {
  return observerPersons()
    .filter { person ->
        val insurance = fetchInsurance(person.insuranceId) // suspending call
        insurance.isValid()
    }
}
```

**delay(), startWith(), concatWith(), ...**

In RxJava you have many operators for applying delay or adding items before and after:

- delay()
- delaySubscription()
- startWith(T)
- startWith(Observable)
- concatWith(...)

with Kotlin Flow you can simply:

```kotlin
grabMyFlow()
  .onStart {
    // delay by 3 seconds before starting
    delay(3000L)
    // just emitting an item first
    emit("First item!")
    emit(cachedItem()) // call another suspending function and emit the result
  }
  .onEach { value ->
    // insert a delay of 1 second after a value only on some condition
    if (value.length() > 5) {
      delay(1000L)
    }
  }
  .onCompletion {
    val endingSequence: Flow<String> = grabEndingSequence()
    emitAll(endingSequence)
  }
```

**error handling**

RxJava have a lot of operators to handle errors:

- onErrorResumeWith()
- onErrorReturn()
- onErrorComplete()

with Flow you don't need much more than the operator `catch()`:

```kotlin
  grabMyFlow()
    .catch { error ->
       // emit something from the flow
       emit("We got an error: $error.message")
       // then if we can recover from this error emit it
       if (error is RecoverableError) {
          // error.recover() here is supposed to return a Flow<> to recover
          emitAll(error.recover())
       } else {
          // re-throw the error if we can't recover (aka = don't catch it)
          throw error
       }
    }
```

and with suspending function you can just use `try {} catch() {}`.

You can achieve ALL the RxJava error operators with a single `catch` operator because you get a suspending function.

**easy to write Flow operators**

Due to the coroutines powering Flow under the hood it is way easier to write operators. If you ever checked an RxJava operator you would see how hard it is and how many things you need to learn.

Writing Kotlin Flow operators is easier, you can get an idea just by looking at the source code of the operators that are already part of Flow [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators). The reason is coroutines make it easier to write async code and operators just feel more natural to use.

As a bonus, Flow operators are all Kotlin Extension Functions, which means either you, or libraries, can easily add operators and they will not feel weird to use (in RxJava `observable.lift()` or `observable.compose()` are needed to combine custom operators).

**Upstream thread doesn't leak downstream**

What does this even mean?

This explains why in RxJava you have `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` while in Flow you only have `flowOn()`.

Let's take this RxJava example:

```kotlin
urlsToCall()
  .switchMap { url ->
    if (url.scheme == "local") {
       val data = grabFromMemory(url.path)
       Flowable.just(data)
    } else {
       performNetworkCall(url)
        .subscribeOn(Subscribers.io())
        .toObservable()
    }
  }
  .subscribe {
    // in which thread is this call executed?
  }
```

So where is the callback in `subscribe` executed?

The answer is:

> it depends...

if it comes from the network it's in an IO thread; if it comes from the other branch it is undefined, depending on which thread is used to send the url.

> If you think about it, any code you write: you don't know in which thread it is gonna be executed: always depends on the caller. The issue here is that the Thread doesn't depend on the caller anymore, it depends on what an internal function call does.
>
> Suppose you have this plain, standard code:
>
> ```kotlin
> fun callUrl(url: Uri) {
>   val callResult = if (url.scheme == "local") {
>     grabFromMemory(url.path)
>   } else {
>     performNetworkCall(url)
>   }
>   return callResult
> }
> ```
>
> Imagine not having a way of knowing in which thread the line `return callResult` is executed in without looking inside `grabFromMemory()` and `performNetworkCall()`.
>
> Think about that for a second: having the thread change based on which function you call and what they do inside.
>
> This happens all the time with callbacks APIs: you have no way of knowing in which thread the callback you provide will be executed unless documented.

*This is the concept of "upstream thread leaking downstream".*

With Flow and Coroutines this is not the case, unless you explicitly require this behavior (using `Dispatchers.Unconfined`).

```kotlin
suspend fun myFunction() {
  // execute this coroutine body in the main thread
  withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    urlsToCall()
      .conflate() // to achieve the effect of switchMap
      .transform { url ->
        if (url.scheme == "local") {
           val data = grabFromMemory(url.path)
           emit(data)
        } else {
           withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
             performNetworkCall(url)
           }
        }
      }
      .collect {
        // this will always execute in the main thread
        // because this is where we collect,
        // inside withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
      }
  }
}
```

Coroutines code will run in the context that they have been executed into. And only the part with the network call will run on the IO thread, while everything else we see here will run on the main thread.

Well, actually, we don't know where code inside `grabFromMemory()` will run, but we don't care: we know that it will be called inside the Main thread, inside that suspending function we could have another Dispatcher being used, but we know when it will get back with the result `val data` this will be again in the main thread.

Which means, looking at a piece of code, it's easier to tell in which thread it will run, if you see an explicit Dispatcher = it's that dispatcher, if you do not see it: in whatever thread dispatcher the suspension call you are looking at is being called.

### Structured Concurrency

This is not a concept invented by Kotlin, but it is something they embraced more than any other language I know of.

If what I explain here is not enough for you read [this article](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952) or watch [this video](https://youtu.be/Mj5P47F6nJg).

So what is it?

With RxJava you subscribe to observables, and they give you a `Disposable` object.

You need to take care of disposing of it when it's not needed anymore. So what you usually do is keep a reference to it (or put it in a `CompositeDisposable`) to later call `dispose()` on it when it's not needed anymore. If you don't the linter will give you a warning.

RxJava is somewhat nicer than a traditional thread. When you create a new thread and execute something on it, it's a "fire and forget", you do not even get a way to cancel it: `Thread.stop()` is deprecated, harmful, and recent implementations actually do nothing. `Thread.interrupt()` makes your thread fail etc.. Any exceptions go lost... you get the picture.

With Kotlin coroutines and flow they reverse the "Disposable" concept. You CANNOT create a coroutine without a `CoroutineContext`.

This context defines the `scope` of your coroutine. Every child coroutine spawned inside that one will share the same scope.

If you subscribe to a flow you have to be inside a coroutine or provide a scope too.

You can still keep a reference of the coroutines you start (`Job`) and cancel them. This will cancel every child of that coroutine automatically.

If you are an Android developer they give you these scopes automatically. Example: `viewModelScope` and you can launch coroutines inside a viewModel with that scope knowing they will automatically be canceled when the ViewModel is cleared.

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
  // my coroutine here
}
```

Some scope will terminate if any children fail, some other scope will let each child leave his own lifecycle without stopping other children if one fails (`SupervisedJob`).

Why is this a good thing?

Let me try to explain it like *Roman Elizarov* did.

Some old programming languages had this concept of `goto` which basically let you jump from one line of code to another at will.

Very powerful, but if abused you could end up with very hard-to-understand code, difficult to debug and reason upon.

So new programming languages eventually completely removed it from the language.

When you use `if` or `while` or `when` it is way easier to reason on the code: doesn't matter what happens inside those blocks, you'll eventually come out of them, it's a "context", you don't have weird jumps in and out.

Launching a thread or subscribing to an RxJava observable is similar to the goto: you are executing code which then will keep going until "elsewhere" is stopped.

With coroutines, by demanding you provide a context/scope, you know that when your scope is over everything inside that coroutine will complete when your context completes, doesn't matter if you have a single coroutine or 10 thousand.

You can still "goto" with coroutines by using `GlobalScope`, which you shouldn't for the same reason you shouldn't use `goto` in languages that provide it.

### Cold vs Hot - ShareFlow and StateFlow

When we work with reactive streams we always have this concept of Cold and Hot streams. Those are concepts on both the Rx world and Kotlin Flows

**Cold** streams are just like a function in our code: it's there and does nothing until you call it. With a Flow that means it is defined what the stream does but it will do nothing until you start to collect on it. And, like a function, if you collect (call) it twice the stream will run twice. (ex. a cold stream to perform an http request will execute the request twice if collected twice).

**Hot** streams do not work like that. When you have multiple collect calls on them they all share the same Hot stream under the hood, which means your hot streams run once and you can have multiple observers.

You can usually turn a Cold stream into a Hot stream with some operator.

**On RxJava** you can use this concept of *Connectable* Observable/Flowable.

```kotlin
val coldObservable: Observable<Something> = buildColdObservable()

// create a hot observable from the cold one
val connectableObservable: ConnectableObservable<Something> = coldObservable.publish()

// you can subscribe multiple times to this connectable
val subADisposable: Disposable = connectableObservable.subscribe(subscriberA)
val subBDisposable: Disposable = connectableObservable.subscribe(subscriberB)

// but nothing will be emitted there until you call
val hotDisposable: Disposable = connectableObservable.connect()

// which actually run the cold observable and share the result on bot subscriberA and subscriberB

// while it's active another one can start listening to it
val subCDisposable: Disposable = connectableObservable.subscribe(subscriberC)
```

You then have other helpful operators like `refCount()` or `autoConnect()` which turn back the `Connectable` into a standard stream and under the hood automatically `.connect()` when the first subscriber is attached.

```kotlin
buildColdObservable()
   .replay(1) // when a new subscriber is attached receive the last data instantly
   .autoConnect() // keep the cold observable alive while there's some subscriber
```

**On Flow** you have the `shareIn()` and the `stateIn()` operators. You can see the API design [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2047). They are less "manual" in handling when you "connect".

```kotlin
buildColdFlow()
  .shareIn(
    // you need to specify a scope for the cold flow subscription
    scope = myScope,
    // when to "connect"
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    // how many events already emitted should be sent to new subscribers
    replay = 1,
  )
```

**scope**

The scope is for structured concurrency. On RxJava it's the `connect()` operation that actually subscribes to the cold observable, it gives you a `Disposable` you will have to call `.dispose()` on somewhere. If you use `refCount()` or `autoConnect()` it is called on the first subscriber and with `refCount()` is never disposed while with `autoConnect()` is disposed when there aren't any more subscribers.

With Flow you need to give a dedicated Scope to collect the cold stream, if you cancel that scope the cold stream will stop emitting and will not be usable anymore.

**started**

So this one is easy

- RxJava `refCount()` --> Flow `SharingStarted.Lazily`, starts collecting on the first subscriber
- RxJava `autoConnect()` -> Flow `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()`, starts collecting on the first subscriber and cancels it when there aren't any more
- RxJava call `connect()` manually before any subscription -> Flow `SharingStarted.Eagerly()`, starts collecting immediately

The `WhileSubscribed()` has useful parameters, [check them out](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-sharing-started/-companion/-while-subscribed.html).

You can also define your own logic for `SharingStarted` to handle when collecting from the cold Flow.

**Behavior and backpressure**

When you have a hot observable you always have backpressure issues to deal with. 1 source of data being listened by many means one listener can be slower than others.

Flow `.shareIn` collects the cold stream in a dedicated coroutine and buffer emission by default. It means if the cold stream emits too fast it will use the buffer. You can change this behavior.

Kotlin `SharedFlow` also lets you access the replay buffer directly to inspect previous emission if you need to.

Canceling a subscriber will have no effect on the shared flow.

using `flowOn()` to change the `Dispatcher` on the subscriber will have no effect on the shared flow (use `flowOn()` before sharing if you need to run the cold stream in some specific dispatcher)

**stateIn**

Flow has a "special" version of `ShareFlow` that is called `StateFlow` and you can use `stateIn()` to create one from another stream.

A `StateFlow` always has 1 value, it cannot be "empty", so you need to provide the initial value when you do `stateIn()`.

A `StateFlow` can never throw exceptions and can never terminate (in this way is similar to `BehaviorRelay` in the RxRelay library)

A `StateFlow` will only emit if the state change (it's like it has a build in `distinctUntilChanged()`.

**RxJava Subjects vs Mutable*Flow**
A `Subject` in RxJava is a class that you can use to manually push your data on it while still using it as a stream.

In Flow you can use `MutableSharedFlow` or `MutableStateFlow` to achieve a similar effect.

With Kotlin coroutines you can also use `Channels` but they are considered somewhat a lower level API.

### Any Drawback?

Flow is still in development and some features available in RxJava might be marked experimental in Kotlin Coroutines Flow or have some difference here and there.

Some niche operator or operator function might not be yet implemented and you might have to implement it yourself (at least it's easier).

But other than that there aren't any drawbacks I know of.

However, there are differences to be aware of that could cause some friction in switching from RxJava and need you to learn new things.

Structured concurrency is a step forward, but introduces a new concept you need to learn and get used to (scopes, supervisorJob): cancellation is handled completely different.

There's some gotcha to be aware of.

**Gotcha: Cancellation Exception**

If you `cancel()` job in a coroutine or `throw CancellationException()` the exception is propagated to parent coroutines unless you used a Supervisor scope / job.
The parent coroutine also cancels sibling coroutines of the one that got canceled if that happens.

BUT if you `catch(e: Exception)`, even using `runCatching {}`, you must remember to rethrow `CancellationException()` otherwise you'll have unexpected results cause the coroutine has been canceled but your code is still trying to execute like it wasn't.

**Gotcha: UncaughtExceptionHandler**

if you do `launch { ... }` to create a new coroutine and that coroutine throws, [by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler), that will terminate the coroutine but will not crash the app and you might completely miss that something went wrong.

This code will not crash your app.

```kotlin
launch {
  throw RuntimeException()
}
```

In some cases it might not even print anything in the log.

If it was a cancellation exception it will definitely NOT print anything in the log.

Comment: thanks, I actually improved it by fixing some mistake in formatting and adding some part i forgot to include

Comment: You rock man, thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge with us all!

Comment: Thanks @DiegoPalomar you gave me motivation to update my answer :)

Comment: Good guide, I do belive that error handling in RX is better, that assumption of "you dont NEED more than a catch" is wrong, there are cases where you need a better default flow control rather than creating that for yourself.

Comment: Care to do an example on when? Cause the way I see it anything you can do in RxJava you can do with that catch operator in Flow.

Comment: @htafoya I've updated my answer, hopefully it will be clearer why you do not need more operators

Comment: Oh my God, this should be put in the google documentation site, as RxJava vs Coroutines

Comment: Excellent comparison and explanation, many thanks for this.

Answer (score 89):

Kotlin coroutines are different from Rx. It is hard to compare them apples-to-apples, because Kotlin coroutines are a thin language feature (with just a couple of basic concepts and a few basic functions to manipulate them), while Rx is a pretty heavy library with quite large variety of ready-to-use operators. Both are designed to address a problem of asynchronous programming, however their approach to solution is very different:

- Rx comes with a particular functional style of programming that can be implemented in virtually any programming language without support from the language itself. It works well when the problem at hand easily decomposes into a sequence of standard operators and not so well otherwise.
- Kotlin coroutines provide a language feature that let library writers implement various asynchronous programming styles, including, but not limited to functional reactive style (Rx). With Kotlin coroutines you can also write your asynchronous code in imperative style, in promise/futures-based style, in actor-style, etc.

It is more appropriate to compare Rx with some specific libraries that are implemented based on Kotlin coroutines.

Take [kotlinx.coroutines library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) as one example. This library provides a set of primitives like `async/await` and channels that are typically baked into other programming languages. It also has support for light-weight future-less actors. You can read more in the [Guide to kotlinx.coroutines by example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md).

Channels provided by `kotlinx.coroutines` can replace or augment Rx in certain use-cases. There is a separate [Guide to reactive streams with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/coroutines-guide-reactive.md) that goes deeper into similarities and differences with Rx.

Comment: What about Error/Exception Handling Management ? Is Rx better than Coroutines ?

Comment: If we compare Rx to kotlinx.coroutines library then they both provide roughly identical error/exception handling capabilities, modulo the style differences. You can either install global error/exception handlers or handle errors locally using various constructs.

Comment: I'd say that coroutines are definitely more flexible in error handling because you can use the good old `try-catch`. You get out-of-the-box scope control that clearly, visually demarcates what you're guarding. You can nest these blocks and code up intricate error handling patterns that are still quite easy to reason about. Syntactically, all a library based on higher-order functions can use is the method chain. Coroutines have the whole language.

Comment: What is an example of a problem/code that does not "easily decompose into a sequence of standard operators"?

Comment: hey Roman congrats on the Kotlin leadership :) anything wrong in my answer to this question?

Answer (score 6):

The talk/doc you linked does not talk about channels. Channels are what fill the gap between your current understanding of coroutines and event driven programming.

With coroutines and channels you can do event driven programming as you are probably used to do with rx, but you can do it with synchronous-looking code and without as many "custom" operators.

If you want to understand this better I suggest to look outside of kotlin, where those concepts are more mature and refined (not experimental). Look at `core.async` from Clojure, Rich Hickey videos, posts and related discussions.

- http://discuss.purelyfunctional.tv/t/core-async-channels-vs-rx-observables/519/2
- https://github.com/matthiasn/talk-transcripts/blob/master/Hickey_Rich/CoreAsync.md

Answer (score 3):

Coroutines are designed to provide a lightweight asynchronous programming framework. Lightweight in terms of resources needed to start the async job. Coroutines don't enforce using an external API and are more natural for the users (programmers). In contrast, RxJava + RxKotlin has an additional data processing package that is not really needed in Kotlin which has a really rich API in the standard library for Sequences and Collections processing.

If you'd like to see more about the practical use of coroutines on Android I can recommend my article:
https://www.netguru.com/codestories/android-coroutines-%EF%B8%8Fin-2020

Answer (score 0):

Coming to RxJava, RxJava streams are prone to leaks, where a stream continues to process items even when you no longer care. Kotlin coroutines use structured concurrency, which makes it much easier to manage the lifecycle of all your concurrent code.RxJava is, as it says on the tin, limited to Java. Coroutines work on any Kotlin-supported platform, so if we ever want to share asynchronous code between Android and iOS we could do it with coroutines.